# Why javascript function return NaN value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

I try to use a int value from a JSON file like

```
{
 "buenos":274.0,
 "desaprobacion":0.13564668769716087,
 "malos":43.0,
 "proporcion":6.372093023255814
}
```

app:

```
var app = angular.module('angularSpa', ['ngRoute','nvd3'])

    .service('QueryService', function($http){
        var urlBase = 'http://localhost:8080/tweets';  
        this.getJson = function(){
            return $http.get(urlBase+"/compañias/vtr");
        };  //I know this works because I use it on another controller to display values ​​inside an html
        //... more functions

})
```

controller:

```
   function getValue(){
        QueryService.getJson()
        .success(function(data){
            return JSON.parse(data.buenos); // here always return NaN
        })
        .error(function(error){
            $scope.status = 'Error at query';
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
```

is there something wrong with the `return` of `getValue()`?

Comment: try using data.data.buenos in success method.

Comment: Where/how/when/what exactly are you coming to the conclusion that this "returns NaN"…? I see no log statement or any place where you use that value…

Comment: Just log the `data` that is passed to the `success` function

Comment: What Manish says, and also JSON.parse() should be angular.fromJson()

Comment: Where are you calling `getValue()`? This code is full of promises, how are you handling them?

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: No :(, i calling in the same controller [http://pastebin.com/JFVrTu56](http://pastebin.com/JFVrTu56)

Answer (score 1):

You parse data.buenos, but your json is in data (JSON.parse(data.buenos);).

You should parse data, then return parsed data buenos.

```
 var a = JSON.parse(data);
 return a.buenos;
```